# Pass variables from Angular component to window object

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an Angular (v4) application and have build a component inside of this application. I need to return 4 values from this component and attach them to the Window object in Javascript, so that they can be processed inside Optimizely. I am looking for an easy and quick way to solve that problem; these are the numbers, that I want to process:

```
  public AmOfWinners: number      = 95682;
  public Week1: number            = 96253;
  public Week2: number            = 97551;
  public Week3: number            = 98247;
```

This is my component:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {downgradeComponent} from "@angular/upgrade/static";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'stats-win',
  template: '<h3>+{{AmOfWinners}}</h3>',
  styles: ['h3 { color: #85AC07; }']

})
export class StatsWinComponent {

  public AmOfWinners: number      = 95682;
  public Week1: number            = 96253;
  public Week2: number            = 97551;
  public Week3: number            = 98247;

  constructor() {
    /* tslint:disable:typedef */
    Observable.interval(604800).subscribe(x => this.AmOfWinners = this.Week1);
    Observable.interval(604800).subscribe(x => this.AmOfWinners = this.Week2);
    Observable.interval(604800).subscribe(x => {
      this.AmOfWinners = this.Week3;
    });
    /* tslint:enable:typedef */
  }


}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    StatsWinComponent
  ],
   entryComponents: [
    StatsWinComponent
  ]
})
export class StatsWinModule {

  public static downgrade(app: ng.IModule): void {
    app.directive('statsWin', downgradeComponent({component: StatsWinComponent}) as ng.IDirectiveFactory);
  }
}
```

As a result, I want to access those numbers in the DOM and process them from there. What would be the best way to do that? Any hints or help would be very much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: have you tried something like `(window as any).AmOfWinners = ` anyway I can't see the need for something like that if you want to data params between components, use services instead, cleaner, better, and make more sense.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: Thank you for your comment, can you go more into detail? I don`t want to pass data inbetween components, but to the window object "outside" of the Angular application,so that it can be accessed by Javascript from elsewhere

Comment: instead of using a public variable, use `Observable.interval(604800).subscribe(x => (window as any).AmOfWinners = this.Week1);` as for example, I'm not sure from where you get values of Week1 - Week3 but anyway try something like that, I just not have time to provide tested solution so this is my comment about it, if this worked, I can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build a service and share. If the variable is changing with condition, assign an observable mechanism like Behavior Subject. But easiest of all is by assigning the variable to window object which is globally available throughout the app. You can assign window[x] = 'y' on component 'x' and avail that value in 'y' component by window.x